# DateAdd function in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

How can I convert `DATEADD(week,-4,GETDATE())`in the where clause ( in Oracle SQL)

Trying to get data for prior 4 weeks

```
SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(C.EMAIL) AS EMAIL, FOI.ORDER_ID AS ORDERS
  FROM MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_FACT_ORDER_ITEMS FOI
  LEFT JOIN MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_DAY D
    ON FOI.ORDER_DATE_SKEY = D.DAY_SKEY
  LEFT JOIN MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_CUSTOMER C
    ON FOI.CUSTOMER_SKEY = C.CUSTOMER_SKEY
 WHERE ((QUANTITY_ORDERED > 0 
   AND FOI.FULFILLMENT_TYPE = 'SCHEDULED_HOME'))
   AND DATEADD(week, -4, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you would use:

```
select sysdate - interval '28' day
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
select sysdate - 4 * interval '7' day
```

Comment: Can i use the same in the where clause as well ?

Comment: @Maddy . . . Yes . . . as long as you include an appropriate comparison.

Comment: I tried it in the below query and it is somehow not working. Could you please help me with this ?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT
       LOWER(C.EMAIL) AS EMAIL,
       FOI.ORDER_ID AS ORDERS
FROM   MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_FACT_ORDER_ITEMS FOI
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_DAY D
       ON FOI.ORDER_DATE_SKEY = D.DAY_SKEY
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MTEPWDATA_CAN.MTEP_DIM_CUSTOMER C
       ON FOI.CUSTOMER_SKEY = C.CUSTOMER_SKEY
WHERE  ( ( QUANTITY_ORDERED > 0
         AND FOI.FULFILLMENT_TYPE='SCHEDULED_HOME'
         )
       )
AND    DATEADD(week,-4,GETDATE())

Comment: @Maddy . . . Like I say, you need an appropriate comparison for the date.  The expression just returns a date.